# what could cause get_stylesheet_directory_uri() to fail?

Tags: css

On my new worpress install, I have code that reads

`<img src="<?php  get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/logo.jpg" />`

This code worked, untill I started using a subdomain (went from example.com/dev to dev.example.com) and changed these urls in my general settings.

Now the `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` does not output anything:

`<img src="/images/logo.jpg" />`

I swapped it with the following: `bloginfo(stylesheet_directory)` which seems to work fine, but I am used to `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` and it seems like this is the reccomended approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would be because `get_stylesheet_directory_uri` only returns a value.  If you want to echo it to to the screen you have to include echo or print.

```
<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/logo.jpg" />
```

`bloginfo` works fine as well, but when you do `stylesheet_directory` it's just a wrapper for `get_stylesheet_directory_uri`

```
<?php
function get_bloginfo( $show = '', $filter = 'raw' ) {

    switch( $show ) {
        // snip snip

        case 'stylesheet_directory':
            $output = get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
            break;
        // snip snip
    }
    $url = true;
    if (strpos($show, 'url') === false &&
        strpos($show, 'directory') === false &&
        strpos($show, 'home') === false)
        $url = false;

    if ( 'display' == $filter ) {
        if ( $url )
            $output = apply_filters('bloginfo_url', $output, $show);
        else
            $output = apply_filters('bloginfo', $output, $show);
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: well i'll be.  I thought I stopped making that mistake a long time ago ;-).  Weird though, I could swear it worked for a time before that domain switch

Comment: how can you output get_stylesheet_directory_uri without wrapping in html img tags? If I have this: `get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/assets/images/geo.jpg';` ?